# Could someone explain me how does sorting of a elements in Java works?

Tags: java, arrays

I am confused from the comment "sorting begins". Could anyone explain this to me.

```
class endsly {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num[] = { 55, 40, 80, 65, 71 };
        int n= num.length;

        System.out.println("Given list:   ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("  " + num[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");

        //sorting begins

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (num[i] < num[j]) {
                    int temp = num[i];
                    num[i] = num[j];
                    num[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sorted list:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("  " + num[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("  ");
    }
}
```

Comment: [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

Comment: This is similar to [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), you can read a pretty good description in Wikipedia.

Comment: @Turing85 Almost. In bubble sort you compare adjacent items. But it's very close.

Comment: Please also not that your question is not about "how sorting elements in Java works", but how a particular code works. `Arrays.sort` or `Collections.sort` (which you'd normally mean by "sorting elements in Java") work quite differently.

Comment: Some remarks on your code: Class names should always start with a capital letter --- `int num[]` Please don't do that, the brackets influence the type, so write them to the type: `int[] num`.

Comment: Can you be more clear, what you can't understand in this code snippet.
This will sort your array in desc order.

Comment: @Turing85 I think it's actually [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort?wprov=sfla1)

Comment: @KevinAnderson it's a weird mix. Selection sort normally only executes one swap after it has selected the minimal element in the unsorted part.

Answer (score 0):

The two nested loops implement a variation of [Selection Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) algorithm with a small "twist" at the end.

- Sorted portion of the array is on the left of `i`, i.e. items from 0, inclusive, to `i`, exclusive
- Nested loop walks the unsorted part, swapping in progressively smaller items into `num[i]`
- By the end of the nested loop the smallest of the unsorted items is in `num[i]`
- By the end of the outer loop the array is sorted

Note that this is different from the "classic" selection sort, which picks the next smallest item from the unsorted array without swapping anything, and performs a single swap at the end of the nested loop. Traditional implementation of selection sort would look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int minPos = i;
    // Look for a position of the smallest element
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (num[minPos] < num[j]) {
            minPos = j;
        }
    }
    // Perform the swap after the loop has ended
    int temp = num[i];
    num[i] = num[minPos];
    num[minPos] = temp
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you have posted is [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) where multiple swaps are permitted, but in reverse (so that the largest elements are placed at the head of the array, rather than the smallest). The general algorithm for selection sort (standard selection sort, where the smallest element is moved to the front of the array) with multiple swaps is:

```
for element i at 0 to n:
    for element j at i to n:
        if element at j is less than element at i:
            swap element at i with element at j
```

Starting at element `0`, the algorithm finds the smallest value from index `0` to index `n` and places it at index `0`. The next iteration, the algorithm finds the smallest value from index `1` to `n` and places it at index `1`. The next iteration, the algorithm finds the smallest value from index `2` to `n` and places it at index `2`. This algorithm continues until the final iteration, which finds the smallest value from index `n - 1` to `n` and places it at index `n`.

In particular case of your algorithm, it is not the smallest value that is found in each iteration, it is the largest. Thus, once the array is sorted, the array is ordered from largest to smallest value. For reference, the conditional in the sorting algorithm is `num[i] < num[j]`, but it may be easier to read this as `num[j] > num[i]`, which means that elements should be swapped if the element at `j` is greater than the element at `i`. You can see each step demonstrated by altering your code to print the value of the array at each step:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int num[] = { 55, 40, 80, 65, 71 };
    int n= num.length;

    System.out.println("Before sorting");
    printArray(num);
    System.out.println();

    //sorting begins

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (num[i] < num[j]) {
                int temp = num[i];
                num[i] = num[j];
                num[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Iteration i = " + i + ": ");
        printArray(num);
    }

    System.out.println("\nAfter sorting");
    printArray(num);
    System.out.println();
}

private static void printArray(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("  " + array[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Executing this code results in the following output:

```
Before sorting
  55  40  80  65  71

Iteration i = 0:   80  40  55  65  71
Iteration i = 1:   80  71  40  55  65
Iteration i = 2:   80  71  65  40  55
Iteration i = 3:   80  71  65  55  40
Iteration i = 4:   80  71  65  55  40

After sorting
  80  71  65  55  40
```

As can be seen in the output, each iteration successively finds the largest value and moves it down. During the first iteration, `80` is moved to index `0`; during the second, `71` is moved to index `1`; and so forth, until 5 iterations (matching the size of `num`) iterations are performed. Although it may appear that iteration `i = 4` is wasted, this is only true for this particular case since the last two elements are already sorted (when `65` and `55` are swapped in iteration `i = 2`).

In general, it is a good idea to step through each iteration of a sorting algorithm to see what the algorithm is doing. This also aids in determining the complexity of the algorithm as well. In this case, a set of nested loops are used, where the outer loop runs from `0` to `n` and the inner loop runs from `i` (starting at `0`) to `n`. This creates the following complexity: *n(n-1)(n-2)...*, or *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. For example, suppose there are `10` elements in the array; the first iteration inner loop will run `10` times; the second iteration inner loop will run `9`; and so on. See the [Wikipedia Selection Sort Complexity Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Complexity) for more information.

---

The algorithm in the question differs from the standard selection sort in that the standard selection sort finds the minimal (or maximal in this case) element from `i` to `n` and performs at most one swap at the end of the iteration. In this case, instead of performing one swap at the end, any time a minimal (or maximal) value is found, the swap is immediately performed, which may result in more than one swap per iteration. This can be demonstrated by instrumenting the algorithm to print the array values each time a swap is performed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int num[] = { 55, 40, 80, 65, 71 };
    int n= num.length;

    System.out.println("Before sorting");
    printArray(num);
    System.out.println();

    //sorting begins

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (num[i] < num[j]) {
                int temp = num[i];
                num[i] = num[j];
                num[j] = temp;
                System.out.print("    Swap performed:");
                printArray(num);
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Iteration i = " + i + ": ");
        printArray(num);
    }

    System.out.println("\nAfter sorting");
    printArray(num);
    System.out.println();
}

private static void printArray(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("  " + array[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
Before sorting
  55  40  80  65  71

    Swap performed:  80  40  55  65  71
Iteration i = 0:   80  40  55  65  71
    Swap performed:  80  55  40  65  71
    Swap performed:  80  65  40  55  71
    Swap performed:  80  71  40  55  65
Iteration i = 1:   80  71  40  55  65
    Swap performed:  80  71  55  40  65
    Swap performed:  80  71  65  40  55
Iteration i = 2:   80  71  65  40  55
    Swap performed:  80  71  65  55  40
Iteration i = 3:   80  71  65  55  40
Iteration i = 4:   80  71  65  55  40

After sorting
  80  71  65  55  40
```